# Having to reload page for Firebase recognize auth

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm working on a small application that has user specific content using twitter auth from Firebase. I have all the auth all set up but when a user logs in, they are forced to reload the page for the site to recognize they have authentication. For example: the user logs in from the log in page and signs in with their twitter account via an `$authWithOAuthPopup` and immediately gets directed to the view with our articles feed. A user has the privilege to save an article to their account but the problem is they are forced to reload the page after their redirect for my application to recognize their authentication. Any have an idea why this might be happening cause this is hella driving me nuts. Libs im using are `angularJS`(`controllerAs` syntax) `angularFire` and `ui.rotuer`

My `auth` factory

```
readyRead.factory('angularAuth', function ($firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject, $state) {
var base = new Firebase('https://readyread.firebaseio.com/')
var users = $firebaseObject(base.child('users'))
var articles = $firebaseArray(base.child('articles'))
var authObj = $firebaseAuth(base)
var authenticated = authObj.$getAuth()
return {
    getAuth: authenticated,
    logIn: function () {
        authObj.$authWithOAuthPopup("twitter").then(function (authData) {
            $state.go('feed.category')
            console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
        })
    },
    logout: function () {
        authObj.$unauth()
    },
    updateUser: base.onAuth(function (authData) {
        if (authData) {
            base.child('users').child(authData.uid).update({
                name: authData.twitter.username,
                displayName: authData.twitter.displayName,
                picture: authData.twitter.cachedUserProfile.profile_image_url,
                isMember: true
            })
          $('.nav-social').prepend(authData.twitter.username)
          $('.social-icon').attr('src', authData.twitter.cachedUserProfile.profile_image_url)
        }
    }),
    saveArticle: function (saved) {
        var userArticles = $firebaseArray(base.child('articles').child(authenticated.uid))
        if (authenticated) {
            userArticles.$add(saved).then(function (base) {
                console.log(saved)
            })
        } else {
            console.log('log in to use this feature')
        }
    }
} })
```

my `routes`

```
readyRead.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: './login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController as login'
    })
    .state('feed', {
        url: '/feed',
        templateUrl: './feed.html',
        controller: 'FeedController as feed'
    })
    .state('feed.read', {
        url: '/read',
        templateUrl: './feed.read.html',
        controller: 'FeedController as feed'
    })
    .state('feed.title', {
        url: '/title',
        templateUrl: './feed.title.html',
        controller: 'FeedController as feed'
    })
    .state('feed.category', {
        url: '/category',
        templateUrl: './feed.category.html',
        controller: 'FeedController as feed'
    })
    .state('userProfile', {
        url: '/userProfile',
        templateUrl: './userProfile.html',
        controller: 'UserProfileController as user'
    }) 
})
```

`controllers` a lot of the action inside of these controllers requires a reload of the page for it to see auth.

```
var readyRead = angular.module('readyRead', ['ngAnimate', 'restangular','firebase', 'ui.router'])
readyRead.config(function(RestangularProvider){
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/')
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams('jsonp',{callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'})
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams({apikey: 'lxZzI5UKXbWL2JK3DL0U2g2uCfMjFUgd'})
})

readyRead.controller('LoginController', function (angularAuth) {
  this.login = angularAuth.logIn
  this.auth = angularAuth.getAuth
  this.logout = angularAuth.logout
  if(this.auth){
    console.log('have auth')
  }else{
    console.log('no auth')
  }
})
readyRead.controller('FeedController', function(api,angularAuth){
  var self = this;
  api.then(function(data){
    self.articles=data.results.collection1
    self.save = angularAuth.saveArticle
  })
})
readyRead.controller('UserProfileController', function(angularAuth,$firebaseObject,$firebaseArray){
  this.auth = angularAuth.getAuth
  var self = this;
  var userBase = $firebaseObject(new Firebase('https://readyread.firebaseio.com/users/'+this.auth.uid))
  var userHistory = $firebaseArray(new Firebase('https://readyread.firebaseio.com/articles/'+this.auth.uid))
  userBase.$loaded()
  .then(function(data) {
    self.name = data.name
    self.avatar = data.picture
    console.log(self.avatar)
  });
  userHistory.$loaded()
  .then(function(data){
    self.list = data
    console.log(self.list)
  })
})
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I'am having the same issue here, and no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you update `authenticated`. You set its value initially when the factory is initialized, and then never again. When user visits from an unauthenticated state, `auth.$authObj()` returns `null` ([$authObj docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html)). You need set it again when the authentication is successful in `logIn`.

If you add this in you `logIn`'s success handler, the user shouldn't have to refresh anymore:

```
authenticated = authData.$authObj()
```

Comment: added that to my `logIn` `.then` callback and still seemed to have to refresh that page. Any other suggestions??

Comment: What is the value of `authenticated` in `saveArticle`, and is your code indeed getting to the point where it sets `authenticated` in `logIn`?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the variables

```
users = $firebaseObject(base.child('users'))
articles = $firebaseArray(base.child('articles'))
```

on login success. That would be...

```
authObj.$authWithOAuthPopup("twitter").then(function (authData) {
    // <--------------- ...here
    $state.go('feed.category')
    console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
})
```